# installed R 2.4 but not R 2.13 in debian

Tags: debian, r

I am trying to install R in my newly-upgraded-to-debian NAS, but it gives something strange like below:

```
NAS-01G:/home/nas01g# apt-get install r-base
Reading Package Lists... Done
Building Dependency Tree... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

Since you only requested a single operation it is extremely likely that
the package is simply not installable and a bug report against
that package should be filed.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  r-base: Depends: r-base-core (>= 2.11.0-1~etchcran.0) but 2.4.0.20061125-1 is to be     installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 2.11.0-1~etchcran.0) but 2.4.0.20061125-1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
NAS-01G:/home/nas01g#
```

What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably added the wrong CRAN repository to your `sources.list` file. Follow the instructions on

http://mirrors.softliste.de/cran/bin/linux/debian/README.html

for your Debian installation. You can check what version of Debian you are using by taking a look at

```
cat /etc/debian_version
```